# What's the Magic Behind Escape(\) Character

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, escaping, backslash

How does the C/C++ compiler manipulate the escape character ["\"] in source code? How is compiler grammar written for processing that character? What does the compiler do after encountering that character?

Comment: at least try to spell your created tags correctly...

Comment: sorry for that, question was typed hastily

Comment: This character (?) is missing in your questions.
What's the rush, though?

Comment: Had urgent meeting minute back question popped up so typed liked that. thanks for modifying :)

Comment: Anyone care to comment on why this question is being pushed down? Is there something I am missing? To me it seems as a fair and correct question to ask.

Comment: Maybe I'm late, but I don't see this question being pushed down at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most compilers are divided into parts: the compiler front-end is called a [lexical analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analyzer) or a scanner. This part of the compiler reads the actual characters and creates tokens. It has a state machine which decides, upon seeing an escape character, whether it is genuine (for example when it appears inside a string) or it modifies the next character. The token is output accordingly as the escape character or some other token (such as a tab or a newline) to the next part of the compiler ([the parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser)). The state machine can group several characters into a token.

Answer (score 6):

An interesting note on this subject is [On Trusting Trust [PDF link]](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ganger/712.fall02/papers/p761-thompson.pdf).

The paper describes one way a compiler could handle this problem exactly, shows how the c-written-in-c compiler does not have an explicit translation of the codes into ASCII values; and how to bootstrap a new escape code into the compiler so that the understanding of the ASCII value for the new code is also implicit.

Comment: That is a very interesting paper which I'd not read in a while.  I'd forgotten the section on boot-strapping a compiler to understand a new escape character sequence such as '\v' - so I didn't immediately see its relevance.  I'm glad I checked it out.

Answer (score 2):

It generally escapes the following character:

- In a string literal or character literal, it means escape the next character. `\a` means 'alert' (flashing the terminal, beeping or whatever), `\n` means 'linefeed', `\xNUM` means an hexadecimal number for example.
- If it appears as the last visible character before a newline, whether within a string or not (and even within a line-wide comment!), it acts as a line-continuation: The following newline character is ignored, and the next line is merged with the current line.

Comment: Don't forget \uXXXX and \UXXXXXXXX in C99.

Comment: \NNN (where N are digits 0-7) represents a byte-number in Octal.
\0, commonly referred to as a Null-Terminator, is really the same as \000.   I think 255 is \377

Comment: Aaron, that's right. there are other uses of \ too. i thought i would list the most important (by subjective measuring).

Answer (score 1):

escape character with a following character (like `\n`) is a single character for C compiler - scanner presents it to parser as character token, so there is no need in special syntax rules in parser for escape character.